# Checking internet connectivity of a system using Java

Tags: java, proxy, httpurlconnection

I wrote a method which will help us finding whether the system using the proxy to connect with internet which is as follows,

```
try {

    System.out.println("Checking internet connection availability.....");
    URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    uc.setReadTimeout(1);//I have tried this without timeout and with it too. But it didnt work
    System.out.println(uc.getResponseCode());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Unable to connect to internet without proxy.....");
    System.out.println("Checking for any proxy settings from the PC");
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
        URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        System.out.println(uc.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Internet connection available");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Internet connection not available :(");
    }
}
```

Initially, I am trying to open the URL connection without proxy (assuming the system don't have proxy to connect with internet).I have set the timeout to 1 ms. Trying to get the response code from the site.
If any error occurs means (like timeout), then in the catch block i am trying to connect to internet with system's proxy, by means of setting the `useSystemProxies` to `true`.
But even after that also, I am not able to get the response from the site.

I am using a system with proxy settings.

I have tried the following too  in the catch block

```
Proxy next = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://www.google.com/")).iterator().next();
if (next.address() != null) {
    System.out.println("Detecting Proxy configurations.....");
    String proxy = next.address().toString();
    String proxyHost = proxy.substring(0, proxy.indexOf(":"));
    String proxyPort = proxy.substring(proxy.indexOf(":") + 1);
    System.out.println("Proxy Configuration : " + proxyHost + " @ " + proxyPort);
}
```

The above block of code also is not working. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

[InetAddress.isReachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29)

> Test whether that address is reachable. Best effort is made by the
>   implementation to try to reach the host, but firewalls and server
>   configuration may block requests resulting in a unreachable status
>   while some specific ports may be accessible. A typical implementation
>   will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege can be obtained,
>   otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo)
>   of the destination host. The timeout value, in milliseconds, indicates
>   the maximum amount of time the try should take. If the operation times
>   out before getting an answer, the host is deemed unreachable. A
>   negative value will result in an IllegalArgumentException being
>   thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet in the catch block try setting the following codes.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "Proxy host");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "Proxy Port");
```

Seems like your proxy is registered as system proxy and not visible to the JVM.